# PHP: Best way to get the connection and logger objects for all classes

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have three classes which I use them for all other classes in the application: Connection, Logger and User (current user info).

What I did, I created a Base Class that instantiate these three classes (I use Symfony, so the Connection and Logger are retrieved as services) inside the Constructor. 
All other classes inherit the Base Class, and don't need to worry about the connection and logger stuff.

I know it's not a good approach, it makes it impossible to inherit from other classes. Also it is hard to test, because the objects are created in the constructor.

Another approach I've tried is to dependency inject these classes into the base class, so I could at least test them. 
However, if I go this route, every time I create an object, I must create the Connection and the Logger before and pass them to the constructor, which makes it very cumbersome to create objects.

I'm aware of the Symfony dependency injection container, but unfortunately, I use my classes not only from Symfony but also from an old Drupal project, so I guess I can't use it.

In short, the question is how would you use your connection and logger all over the application, in a way that it'll be easy to use and testable.

Edit: Example of the Base Class I'm using now:

```
class BaseModel {
    protected $connection;
    protected $logger;

    public function  __construct() {
        $kernel = $this->getKernelInstance();
        $this->connection = $kernel->getContainer()->get('database_connection');
        $this->logger = $kernel->getContainer()->get('logger');
    }

    public static function getKernelInstance() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've answered the question yourself: Dependency Injection. You can also use the container safely. Symfony is a set of reusable components which were built in a decoupled way so that you can use them everywhere including in your Drupal project. As a matter of fact, Drupal 8 was built on top of Symfony components including the Dependency Injection component and its container. Besides, you can use [other](http://php-di.org/) containers, or create your own.

Comment: Correct, I can use DI in Drupal (which is Drupal 5 by the way), but it makes creating new classes and instantiating objects very cumbersome. Currently, all I need to do is `Class MyClass extends BaseClass`. With DI, I have to add to the YML file all the dependancies (which are the same for all classes). To create an object, currently all I need to do is `$myClass = new MyClass`, with DI, I need to create a ContainerBuilder() in Drupal, load the YML file from Symfony, then I can use get() to get the service. Also, this way I don't have auto-complete (my IDE is PHPStorm).

Comment: You asked for the best way which is using a DI container, as it follows the dependency inversion principle. You'll easily test your classes thanks for being dependent upon abstractions vs concretions. However, it might be cumbersome for a simple project, so you should consider using the anti patterns Singleton, Multiton or Registry. This is not best practice for gigantic platforms, but I can tell you can still unit test with them too.

Comment: It **is** a big project. I'm trying to find the balance between easy to use and best practice / testable. In addition to what I mentioned before, when using DI, I have to add to each one of my classes the connection and logger variables, add a constructor that set their values. Sounds like a duplicate code to me. (maybe I can solve the last one by using trait). I prefer not to use anti-patterns.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something with how to use DIC. I didn't find a real-world and complete example of how to create and **use** a Symfony DIC.

Comment: You can at least free up the constructor by using setter injection.  In addition, you can do what Symfony does with their base controller class which is to inject the entire container.  But the real question is why do you have so many classes that require these three standard injections but which at the same time cannot themselves be created using a container?  Your design might actually be the source of your problem.

Comment: Moving it to the setter, still requires me to do it for all classes. (Lots of code - same code for many classes). Injecting the entire container helps a bit, but I still need to create variables somewhere of the connection/logger and assign the value from the container. Regarding the design - I'll simplify it, think about the Model part, when you have many classes that mostly fetch data from the DB. All classes in my Model need a DB connection and a logger. Not sure what do you mean by "cannot themselves be created using a container", I can, but how it helps me?

Comment: If you pull them out of a container then your manual constructor problems go away.  Sound like you are stuck with an active record implementation of some sort?  You could wrap up the three dependencies into one object and inject it.  But I don't understand where the "lots of duplicate code" comes from.  Maybe you could post your base constructor.  And maybe for you app, using global singletons might be the best approach.  Don't get overly hung up on design patterns and "best" practices.

Comment: The manual constructor problems when creating objects indeed go away, yet when creating a new class (not new object), it requires to create the variables and the constructor, which is the same for all classes (that's why I refer them as duplicate). I've added my base class to the question, if I use DI, it seems to me that every class I create will be a duplicate of the base class (except the getKernelInstance method). I think wrapping up the dependencies into one object is basically the same as injecting the container (?). It's not active records, just a simple read/write from old Drupal DB.

Answer (score 1):

`Factory` pattern to the solution:

A factory object is responible for the creation and initialisation of nontrivial objects. And your situation is a prime example for using one.

In your example you have to create all sorts of model objects, which require a logger, the database connection and the user object. This can be done by a factory. If the constructor signature is predictable enough (seems to be the case), then you don't even have to create different factories for each class since in PHP you can create new objects with just `new $className($connection, $logger, $user)`.

The DI's responsibility is to inject the connection, the logger and the user into the factory. By the way, the DI also allows you to create a service by using any object in the container as a [factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html).

You can also consider using marker interfaces to automate setter injection. The DI can be configured to scan for all service objects implementing a `*Aware` interface (ContainerAware and LoggerAware are famous for doing that), and perform setter injection on them. [Check out this blog post for details](http://toschas.com/aware-interfaces-symfony2/).

To improve testability I'd also recommend to create an interface for your factory class so that it be exchanged (also known as the Abstract Factory pattern).